# Django ChoiceField populated from database values

Tags: django, choicefield

I am having problems using a ChoiceField to create a drop down list of values in the database. Here is the snippet of code

```
from django import forms
from testplatform.models import ServiceOffering

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    subject = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=ServiceOffering.objects.all())
    #subject = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ServiceOffering.objects.all())
```

The #subject.... line works, but when I use the line ChoiceField(queryset....) I get the following error.

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`ChoiceField` doesn't have a queryset. You're looking for `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: Excellent - that worked a treat. I get a ------ as a default value in the drop down box. Can I change that? Thanks!

Comment: If shows that way if the field is optional, set the field on the form to `required=True` to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to populate dropdown list from database, I'll recommend you to pass all the values in single object from views.py to your template. You can do it this  way:
1] fetch all the values from database:

```
objectlist = ModelName.objects.all()
```

if you want sorted list in dropdown list, Do this:

```
objectlist = ModelName.objects.all().order_by('fieldname')
```

if you want distinctlist, do this:

```
objectlist = ModelName.objects.distinct('fieldname')
```

2] Pass this render this 'objectlist' with template

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'objectlist': objectlist})
```

3] In template use a select tag , and in user for loop to iterate over the objectlist.

```
<select>


{% for element in objectlist %}


<option value={{ element.id }}>{{ element.name }}



     </select>
```

**value in  option tag depends on what you need to process in your API**

Answer (score 3):

Use the **ModelChoiceField** [Link Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

**ChoiceField** doesn't support queryset

Comment: thanks - got it.. I suppose I can use the initial value so I don't see the ------ appear?

Comment: @Oli Yeah you can use the initial value to get rid of ---- set initial = "Some value"

Answer (score 1):

view.py :- 
This is my view.py file. And create below code.

```
def add_customer(request):
    objectlist = Vehicle.objects.values('brand_name').distinct().order_by('brand_name')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/show-customers')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'add-customer.html', {'form':form, 'objectlist':objectlist})
```

Customer.html

```
<select name="prefer_car_model" id="id_prefer_car_model" required>
                <option value="0" selected disabled> Select Car model </option>
                {% for obj in objectlist %}
                <option value="{{ obj.brand_name }}">{{ obj.brand_name }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

***Output***

[image: VMS - Vehicle Brand Name Lists]

Comment: Hi Thai, adding a bit more explanation around your solution, rather than merely posting code, would make it a great response.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2+ you can use 'choices' instead of 'queryset'