# How save marks in checkboxs?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.10

Can someone say, how create such form as in the picture below in Django?

[image]

I have model `Product` with field `is_visable`. In form I want to show all products with field `is_visable`. User can select checkboxes and change the value of `is_visable` field. In other words make products visable or invisable. I am thing about `MultipleChoiceField` in my form but not sure is it correct in my case.

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Product.objects.all())
```

**views.py:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProductForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ids = form.cleaned_data.get('product')  # Example: ['pk', 'pk']
        for id in ids:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
            product.is_visible = True
            product.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) in your form with a widget of [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple).

A queryset for the ModelChoiceField is a required argument, so you can build the queryset like this:

```
visible_products =  Product.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
product_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=visible_products,
                                 widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple()
```

See this post for more details:

[Django ChoiceField populated from database values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936470/django-choicefield-populated-from-database-values)

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post again pls. I add form and view code. I show all products in form, then change is_visable value of products which was clicked by user in views. But I steal dont understand how to save mark in checkbox in that products which has 'is_visable=True'? Do you have any ideas about that?